# How to replace values in Dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one large dataframe that currently has both "?", "??", and NaN values that I'm trying to remove. I want to redefine the columns to be booleans to see whether they contained "?", "??" or NaN.

My current approach involves cloning different columns of the dataframe based on whether they contain just "?", just "??" or just NaN values and separately iterating through the columns, col, to change the values (ex: df[col] = df[col].isnull()) and finally merging them together again.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by *remove*? do you mean dropping the rows that contain ?,?? or NaN or changing them to something else?

Comment: Replace the question mark strings using a dictionary containing pairs of values to replace and what you want to replace them with. 
    
    df.replace({'?':'', '??':''}, inplace=True)

You need to be specific about what you want to do with the NaNs. Do you want to drop the rows or columns? Do you want to replace NaNs with a filler value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

how about using quick-sort algorithm. And, I am not sure I got what your data looks like and what results you want to obtain. Maybe you could show us parts of your data frame.

Comment: I think this response is more like a comment than an answer

Comment: I think this will serve better as a comment and not as an answer.